# In Google's Closure Compiler, what is the difference between {Element} and {HTMLElement}?

Tags: javascript, annotations

Closure Compiler defines both {Element} and {HTMLElement}, {Document} and {HTMLDocument}. How should I choose which one to use to get the most from Closure Compiler?

They aren't simply the same thing. Sometimes one will lead to a Closure Compiler error message while the other won't. Sometimes one can be used in a valid Closure Compiler "cast" that the other can't.

(Perhaps the difference has something to do with DOM1 vs. DOM2, but what? [And why does it matter?] Should I always use one or the other in Javascript that will run exclusively on HTML5?)

---

EDIT: I'm looking for a "rule of thumb" that tells me in a quick-and-dirty way how to write good code. (This may of course be a "summary" or a "really means" of some specifications.)

Comment: Reading documentation helps: [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

Comment: @teemu I must have taken too many stoopid pills this morning, as even after reading I can't figure out which one I should use while annotating some existing Javascript code for Closure Compiler, or why. Do I now understand correctly that this is a Javascript thing that Closure Compiler is just reflecting, not something specific to Closure Compiler itself? Beyond that, I ran into the usual specification problem that everything refers to everything else, so nothing makes much sense without reading for hours and hours and hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Element` unless something in the code's use uses an `HTMLElement` specific property.

[HTMLElement specific properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement):

```
HTMLElement.accessKey
HTMLElement.accessKeyLabel (Read only)
HTMLElement.contentEditable
HTMLElement.contextMenu 
HTMLElement.dir
HTMLElement.draggable
HTMLElement.dropzone (Read only)
HTMLElement.hidden
HTMLElement.inert
HTMLElement.innerText
HTMLElement.isContentEditable (Read only)
HTMLElement.itemId 
HTMLElement.itemProp (Read only)
HTMLElement.itemRef (Read only)
HTMLElement.itemScope 
HTMLElement.itemType (Read only)
HTMLElement.itemValue 
HTMLElement.lang
HTMLElement.noModule
HTMLElement.offsetHeight (Read only)
HTMLElement.offsetLeft (Read only)
HTMLElement.offsetParent (Read only)
HTMLElement.offsetTop (Read only)
HTMLElement.offsetWidth (Read only)
HTMLElement.properties (Read only)
HTMLElement.spellcheck
HTMLElement.style
HTMLElement.title
HTMLElement.translate
```

[HTMLElement specific Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement):

```
HTMLElement.oncopy 
HTMLElement.oncut 
HTMLElement.onpaste 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchstart 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchend 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchmove 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchenter 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchleave 
TouchEventHandlers.ontouchcancel
```

[HTMLElement specific methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement):

```
HTMLElement.attachInternals() 
HTMLElement.click()
HTMLElement.forceSpellCheck()
```